# Type annotations: Using numpy and pure python types with generics

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, mypy

I'm struggling to annotate a function which accepts tuples of `int` or `floats` and produces a numpy array with `dtype`s `np.integer` or `np.floating`:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Tuple, Union, TypeVar
import numpy as np


T = TypeVar('T', np.integer, np.floating)

def bounds2loc(bounds: Tuple[T, T, T, T]) -> np.ndarray[Tuple[int], np.dtype[T]]:
    left, top, right, bottom = bounds
    loc = np.asarray([left, top])
    return loc


def do_check_int() -> np.ndarray[Tuple[int], np.dtype[np.integer]]:
    bounds = (1, 2, 10, 5)
    bounds2loc(bounds)
```

Mypy check reasonably fails, as pure python's `int` cannot be casted to `np.integer`: `Argument 1 to "bounds2loc" has incompatible type "Tuple[int, int, int, int]"; expected "Tuple[integer[Any], integer[Any], integer[Any], integer[Any]]"`.

Is there a way to make a proper annotation which would allow that?.

Comment: You can use [`overload`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#function-overloading) to declare multiple signatures: `(tuple[int, int, int, int]) -> np.ndarray[tuple[int], np.dtype[np.integer]]`, `(tuple[float, float, float, float]) -> np.ndarray[tuple[float], np.dtype[np.floating]]`, etc.(I'm not sure how numpy typing works, so may be wrong with `ndarray` type parameters).